# What is the role of mask parameter in glStencilFunc

Tags: opengl, glsl

In the function

```
glStencilFunc(GLenum func, GLint ref, GLuint mask)
```

what is the role of mask , we are sending the ref value and the buffer content is being compared to the ref value than why do we need to send mask value ?

what i read about the mask value is    "mask that is ANDed with both the reference value and the stored stencil value"    but why do we need that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on what you're doing with the stencil. Some stencil operations treat the stencil value as just an integer, incrementing and/or decrementing the stencil value for some effect or purpose. Other operations use it as a bitmask, where each bit or group of bits in the stencil value represents something in particular. That is, from a semantic perspective, you have multiple values that just so happen to be stored in the same 8 bits of space.

The `mask` value is for cases like that. You might have 8 separate masking regions, and you want to render some geometry against one of the region. You use the `mask` parameter to specify which bit (that specifies a region) to mask off a piece of geometry.

Answer (score 0):

It also allows you to control the value written to the stencil buffer, by swapping the values of "ref" and "mask".

Ordinarily, glStencilFunc both *checks* against *ref*, and if a fragment passes the test, *ref* is also *written* to the stencil buffer. This limits the operations you can do, since you can only operate on bitmasks that you then also write.

But since AND is symmetric, *mask* and *ref* are actually the exact same parameter, with the difference that *ref* will be written to the buffer.